# Parsing json file to get out data

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

Using winforms in c# with following nuget packages

```
WindowsAPICodePack-Shell //used for old style folder dialog
Newtonsoft.Json
```

I have a folder of files with the following structure

```
{
    "modelName": "3K05",
    "Fridge":  
    { 
    "color" : "white",
    "comment" : "sell at discount",  
    "version" : 1,  
    "date" : 20171102,  
    "features" : 264, 
    "purpose" : "Generic",  
    "format" : [1,5,10,0],  
    "build" : [[0,0,0,0,0,0], 
    [22,0,0,20,0,0], 
    [0,30,0,0,0,0], 
    [26,0,0,31,0,90], 
    [0,0,33,0,0,0], ]
    }  
    }
```

I then try to parse through to get out some information using the following code

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(dialog.FileName))
                {
                   if (Path.GetExtension(filename) == ".APP") //name of json files
                   {
                       using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename)) //read infile
                       {
                         dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r.ReadToEnd()); //put into json array
                         foreach (var item in array) //parse thru array
                         {
                             if (item.modelName != null) listBox1.Items.Add(item.modelName); else listBox1.Items.Add("empty"); // get modelName

                             if (item.Fridge != null) listBox1.Items.Add(item.Fridge.color); else listBox1.Items.Add("empty"); //get color

                             if (item.Fridge != null) listBox1.Items.Add(item.Fridge.format); else listBox1.Items.Add("empty"); //get the string inside []

                             if (item.Fridge != null) listBox1.Items.Add(item.Fridge.build); else listBox1.Items.Add("empty"); //get second item as string [[ ] [ 2nd]]
                            }
                       }                       
                   }
                }
```

The first issue is that I cannot get anything to work unless I enclose my data in square bracket []. so how can I make it work without teh square bracket?

My working data is

```
[
{
"modelName": "3K05",
"Fridge":  
{ 
"color" : "white",
"comment" : "sell at discount",  
"version" : 1,  
"date" : 20171102,  
"features" : 264, 
"purpose" : "Generic",  
"format" : [1,5,10,0],  
"build" : [[0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[22,0,0,20,0,0], 
[0,30,0,0,0,0], 
[26,0,0,31,0,90], 
[0,0,33,0,0,0], ]
}  
} 
]
```

Second question is how do I now get the information from build and format. From build I want to be able to get the second item as a string?

```
22,0,0,20,0,0
```

At present it comes up as collection. I can see how to get into t the first one if have as Fridge.color which returns white but how do I go into Fridge.build.?

---

How I got mine working is a mixture from the answers so thanks to all who answered.

I learnt a new part of VS that is Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as classes

Then I consumed it as

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText(@filename)); 

myObject.xxxx.yyyyy;
```

xxxx = Rootobject instance of Json class
yyyy = item in Json class. That is how I understand it but the words I use may not be correct.

Doing it this way also shows me that the build info is just a 2 dimensional array which I am happy to work with.

Again thanks to this site I learned a whole lot more about C#

Comment: For your first question, your JSON is not valid, replace **[0,0,33,0,0,0],** with **[0,0,33,0,0,0]**. Also, please dont use dynamic , please read the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) this will help you with you second question if you map your json into class, you can easily do this with [this tool](http://json2csharp.com/) (**Edit**) If you how the build structure work you can map it to another sub class

Comment: First issue: u are iterating through your dynamic object with a foreach, so it expects an array from the json, therefore u have to wrap the json inside [ ] brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/), the following class(es) models your json.

```
public class Fridge
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int features { get; set; }
    public string purpose { get; set; }
    public List<int> format { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> build { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string modelName { get; set; }
    public Fridge Fridge { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you can also do this in Visual Studio, as long as your json string is valid. Just go to **Edit->Paste Special**..

You can then consume as follows:

```
var myObject=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>();
//get the format list
var formats=myObject.Fridge.format;
var build=myObject.Fridge.build;
```